# How to fit a DIV with height:100% on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I'm hiding a `.contact` div off screen like so:

```
#contact {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100%;
  top:100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: $sdpblack;
  padding: $gutter;

  /* Media query for handheld devices */
  @include max-screen($palm) {
     height:100%;
     display:table;
     padding-left:0; //Because we just switched to table display
  }
}
```

When then user clicks a button, I use jQuery to slide the form up like this:

```
$scope.contactIsUp = false;
$scope.toggleContact = function( event ) {
    speedup = 500;
    speeddown = 300;
    if ( $scope.contactIsUp ) { //lowering
        $('#contact').animate({'margin-top':0},speeddown, function(){ //who cares });
    } else { //raising
        var height = $('#contact').outerHeight();
        alert('css height: '+$('#contact').css('height'));
        alert('height: '+height);
        alert( 'window.outerHeight: '+$(window).outerHeight() );
        alert( 'window.innerHeight: '+$(window).innerHeight() );
        $('#contact').animate({'margin-top':'-='+height},speedup);
        $scope.contactIsUp = true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I use negative `margin-top` to bring the div into view because the final position differs depending on the screen size. On desktops, the div sits along the bottom edge of the window. On smartphones, it fills the screen from top to bottom.

**PROBLEM:** On an iPhone, the contact form slides up stops 36px from the top. This does not seem to be a problem on an iPad.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

NOTE: I *really* don't want to resort to sniffing the client. Ick!

Comment: Is there supposed to be a closing bracket for your #contact css?

Comment: @JoeKomputer Yes. Fixed.

Comment: the culprit is the box-sizing:border-box; Safari seems to handle it differently then other browsers in this particular situation.

Comment: AHA! I had a hunch that might have something to do with it. Any ideas on a clean fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is box-sizing:border-box;

box-sizing:border-box; isn't really necessary if your css doesn't have margins or padding that would stretch your body outside the windows limits. It's nice tool to fall back on, but if your css is clean you really don't need it. I'd take it out, make sure there isnt any padding or margins spilling outside the windows limits. And I'd use translate3d() instead of top:100%. It hardware accelerates animations like sliding and makes them look much better.

Comment: I can confirm that the box-sizing IS the culprit. When I remove it things work properly on iOS but I *do* have padding that would stretch my content outside the width of the screen, so simply removing the box-sizing property breaks the layout on larger screens.

Comment: Taking a look at your css I don't see any elements that spill out of the window. Is there a specific screen size that looks broken without box-sizing?

Comment: Scratch that. The DIV in question has `position:absolute;` so I can get away with `left:0; right:0;` and remove the `box-sizing`. Lucky me.

As for optimizing the animation, could you add a bit more on your suggestion to use `translate3d()` instead of `top:100%`. I think I loose IE9 if I use `translate3d()`...

Comment: It looks like I can get away with `-ms-translateY()` on IE9.

Comment: top:100% is essentially the same as translate3d(0,100%,0) so to animate from below screen to in screen you'd animate from translate3d(0,100%,0) to translate3d(0,0,0) or whatever you want your Y value to be. Here is a quickly thrown together [example](http://jsfiddle.net/S9w5d/). And as far as early ie support goes you can always put a condition in that uses different animation methods if the browser doesnt support translate3d.